# How to remove list from validation summary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I added ValidationSummary Html helper for my View Model class which has 5 required fields. And it works  got nice red words missing 1, missing 2 etc. 
But I need to display just one message not five of them (something like: "Your input is not valid."). Can this be done with ValidationSummary?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have two options (at least):

Either use the validation summary and exclude property errors:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "The input is not valid")
```

or associate a error message with a custom key in your action:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("myerrorsummary", "The input is not valid");
}
```

and display it on your page:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("myerrorsummary")
```

Comment: The first solution seems best because it should work client side, but it only works when not using UnobtrusiveJavaScript!

Answer (score 4):

You can try skipping the helpers if all you want to do is simply *display* a message if the ModelState is not valid. Simply check the `ModelState` within `ViewData` and that should work.

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <p>Your input is not valid.</p>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at MVC3 source code you'll see that, currently, if you use `ValidationSummary` with `excludePropertyErrors=true` while having `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled`, there won't be any validation summary rendered.

I was able to display just a single message with MVC3 with UnobtrusiveJavascript enabled, for client side validation. Don't use `@Html.ValidationSummary` at all, and render:

```
@{
    //Show the message when there are server side errors
    ViewBag.ValidationSummaryClass = ViewData.ModelState.IsValid ? "validation-summary-valid" : "validation-summary-errors";
}
<div class="@ViewBag.ValidationSummaryClass" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <span>Before you can continue, please make sure you have completed the mandatory fields highlighted above.</span>
    <ul style="display:none"/>
</div>
```

Notice the `display:none`, unobtrusive javascript still fills the list with error messages, but they are kept hidden.

Answer (score 0):

One brute force approach I've used in MVC3:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Some contextual error message");
}
```

and display it on your page:

```
<% if(!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) { %>
    <span class="error"><%=ViewData.ModelState[String.Empty].Errors[0].ErrorMessage %> </span>
<% } %>
```